# Convert unorderer list html <ul> to json array with recursive call to the sub-list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-lists

I'm trying to create an efficient method in javascript to convert with jquery (and bootstrap if you have some snippet), a unordered HTML list

  to a JSON array.
  I put an example for make myself clearer:

**Html test**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="treeview">
<ul class="menu_level0_container list-group mymenu">
<li class="menu_level0  menu_level0_hasChildren" id="Test1_listElement"><a href="/test1" class="menu_level0_link menu_level0_link_hasChildren " id="Test1">test1</a>
    <ul class="menu_level1_container " id="Test1_sub">
        <li class="menu_level1 " id="test11_listElement"><a href="/test11" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test11">test11</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level1 " id="test12_listElement"><a href="/test12" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test12">test12</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level1 last1 " id="test13_listElement"><a href="/test13" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test13">test13</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu_level0  menu_level0_hasChildren" id="test2_listElement"><a href="/test2" class="menu_level0_link menu_level0_link_hasChildren " id="test2">test2</a>
    <ul class="menu_level1_container " id="test2_sub">
        <li class="menu_level1 " id="test21_listElement"><a href="/test21" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test21">test21</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level1 " id="test22_listElement"><a href="/test22" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test22">test22</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level1 last1 " id="test23_listElement"><a href="/test23" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test23">test23</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu_level0 last0 " id="test3_listElement"><a href="/test3" class="menu_level0_link  " id="test3">test3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Here the script i made so far but , is not very good and have some errors i can't figure out how to solve:

```
<script>
var data = [];
function walk4(nodes, data) {

if (!nodes) { return; }
nodes.find("li").each(function (id, node) {
    console.log('(' + id + ')Node:' + JSON.stringify(node, null, 0));
    var text = jQuery(this).contents().get().map(function (n) { return n.nodeType === 3 ? n.textContent.trim() : ''; }).join(''); //get current node text
    var obj = {
        id: id,
        text: text,
        tags: [jQuery(this).children > 0 ? jQuery(this).children + ' child elements' : '']
    };

    if(jQuery(this).has("ul")){
      obj.nodes = [];
      walk4(jQuery(this).find("ul"), obj.nodes); //recursive call
    }
    console.log('(' + id + ')OBJ:' + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 0));
    data.push(obj);     


 });
}       


var nodes = $("#treeview").find("ul");
walk4(nodes,data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,0)); //here my json array
</script>
```

What i want it's the "data" variabile set with this result:

```
[
{text: 'test1', textHtml: '<a href="/test1" class="menu_level0_link menu_level0_link_hasChildren " id="Test1">test1</a>', href:'/test1',
        nodes: [   {id:'test11',text: 'test11', textHtml: '<a href="/test11" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test11">test11</a>', href:'/test11', tags['0']},
                        {id:'test12',text: 'test12', textHtml: '<a href="/test12" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test12">test12</a>', href:'/test12', tags['0']},
                        {id:'test13',text: 'test13', textHtml: '<a href="/test13" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test13">test13</a>', href:'/test13',tags['0']}
        ], tags['3']},
{text: 'test2', textHtml: '<a href="/test2" class="menu_level0_link menu_level0_link_hasChildren " id="Test2">test2</a>', href:'/test2',
        nodes: [   {id:'test21',text: 'test21',  textHtml: '<a href="/test21" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test21">test21</a>', href:'/test21', tags['0']},
                        {id:'test22',text: 'test22', textHtml: '<a href="/test22" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test22">test22</a>', href:'/test22', tags['0']},
                        {id:'test23',text: 'test23', textHtml: '<a href="/test23" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test23">test23</a>', href:'/test23', tags['0']}
        ], tags['3']},
{text: 'test3', textHtml:'<a href="/test3" class="menu_level0_link  " id="test3">test3</a>', href:'/test3', tags['0']}
]
```

NOTE: not very important the structure of the JSON, I just want to convert all the info in a HTML unordered list  to a JSON array.

**I will try to update this question by myself when i will found a solution**, but if anyone has some advise is more than welcome.

Ty in advance for any help.

**UPDATE (Suggestion from guest271314)**: NOw the JSON result is:

```
[
  {"id":0,"text":"","tags":["2 child elements"],
"nodes":[ {"id":0,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
                {"id":1,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
                {"id":2,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]}
]},
{"id":1,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
{"id":2,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
{"id":3,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
{"id":4,"text":"","tags":["2 child elements"],
"nodes":[
                {"id":0,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
                {"id":1,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
                {"id":2,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]}
                ]},
{"id":5,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
{"id":6,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
{"id":7,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]},
{"id":8,"text":"","tags":["1 child elements"],"nodes":[]}
]
```

Some error on the code can't get the text current node (it's different from the innerText of the node)

duplicate object, the children already present in a parent array "nodes" must not be re-appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.childElementCount` is not a jQuery method. Substitute `.children().length` for `.childElementCount`

```js
var data = [];
function walk4(nodes, data) {

if (!nodes) { return; }
nodes.find("li").each(function (id, node) {
    console.log('(' + id + ')Node:' + JSON.stringify(node, null, 0));
    var text = jQuery(this).contents().get().map(function (n) { return n.nodeType === 3 ? n.textContent.trim() : ''; }).join(''); //get current node text
    var obj = {
        id: id,
        text: text,
        tags: [jQuery(this).children().length > 0 ? jQuery(this).children().length + ' child elements' : '']
    };

    if(jQuery(this).has("ul")){
      obj.nodes = [];
      walk4(jQuery(this).find("ul"), obj.nodes); //recursive call
    }
    console.log('(' + id + ')OBJ:' + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 0));
    data.push(obj);     


 });
}       


var nodes = $("#treeview").find("ul");
walk4(nodes,data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,0)); //here my json array
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="treeview">
<ul class="menu_level0_container list-group mymenu">
<li class="menu_level0  menu_level0_hasChildren" id="Test1_listElement"><a href="/test1" class="menu_level0_link menu_level0_link_hasChildren " id="Test1">test1</a>
    <ul class="menu_level1_container " id="Test1_sub">
        <li class="menu_level1 " id="test11_listElement"><a href="/test11" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test11">test11</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level1 " id="test12_listElement"><a href="/test12" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test12">test12</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level1 last1 " id="test13_listElement"><a href="/test13" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test13">test13</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu_level0  menu_level0_hasChildren" id="test2_listElement"><a href="/test2" class="menu_level0_link menu_level0_link_hasChildren " id="test2">test2</a>
    <ul class="menu_level1_container " id="test2_sub">
        <li class="menu_level1 " id="test21_listElement"><a href="/test21" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test21">test21</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level1 " id="test22_listElement"><a href="/test22" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test22">test22</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level1 last1 " id="test23_listElement"><a href="/test23" class="menu_level1_link  " id="test23">test23</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu_level0 last0 " id="test3_listElement"><a href="/test3" class="menu_level0_link  " id="test3">test3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @4535992 Does `js` at post return expected result?